# react-native autolink dependencies used in custom library

Tags: react-native, autolink

So I build a library, and I am using some external libraries in it.

This is the package.json

```json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "*",
    "crypto-js": "*",
    "js-base64": "*",
    "react-native": "^0.0.0-0 || 0.60 - 0.69 || 1000.0.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-2": "*",
    "react-native-windows": "*"
  },
```

Now when I install my library, the `peerDependencies` gets installed automatically.

The problem is that those installed automatically dose not autolink.
for example for `react-native-sqlite-2` to link, I have to installed manually to eg `npm install react-native-sqlite-2`

Why is that? should those libraries not autolink by them self? or is there a configuration that I am missing ?